# Does mvvm light v3 unregister work properly?

Tags: mvvm-light

Is there a problem with the MvvM-Light v3 unregister?

I am registering like this:

```
 Messenger.Default.Register<DialogResponse>(this,
                                            MessageTypesUI.YesNoQueryResponse,
                                            AnswerResponse);
```

Then in "AnswerResponse"

```
 Messenger.Default.Unregister<DialogResponse>(MessageTypesUI.YesNoQueryResponse);
```

Both methods execute, and AnswerResponse is called, but the second time it is called twice and the third time thrice, etc.

It acts as if my "Unregister" is being ignored.

I tried it both with Unregister() and plain old Unregister()

There was something in the release notes for V4 that made me suspect a problem with the version 3 unregister...

Answer (score 6):

You should modify the call to Unregister to pass in the recipient object, not the message type:

```
Messenger.Default.Unregister<DialogResponse>(this);
```

If you look at the [MVVM Light code](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/3bdbffb4e70a#GalaSoft.MvvmLight%2fGalaSoft.MvvmLight%20%28NET35%29%2fMessaging%2fMessenger.cs) for the messenger all unregister actions use the recipient - as internally the recipient is used for identifying which message handlers will be removed. The most basic method is `Unregister(recipient)`, which de-registers all actions for a given recipient. All additional parameters allow for a more fine grained approach.

If you have multiple actions handling the same message type and you want to unregister only one of them you can use

```
Messenger.Unregister<DialogMessage>(recipient, action);
```

to only remove one of the actions.

**Edit**

The MVVM Light release notes for V. 4 indicate the following changes to the Messenger:

1. Missing methods where added to. The IMessenger interface.
2. An additional Unregister method allowing to use tokens for filtering was added.
3. The Messenger.CleanupList method was made thread safe.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! It came to me in the middle of the night: how would Messenger know who I am? But I much appreciate the confirmation. Should have looked closer at the IntelliSense. (duh)

Comment: @Obalix, yes, this _is_ the correct answer, whether or not OP thought of it himself or not.