# Registering for messages outside of a ViewModel in MVVM Light?

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, mvvm-light

I was trying to register for a message outside of a ViewModel in a static constructor but apparently that registration didn't take: the registered action never ran when messages were sent. I tried passing in null or a new object for the `recipient` parameter when registering but that didn't work.

I have a feeling the specifying the recipient must be important somehow, but I don't know why. I thought that all recipients were supposed to get broadcasted messages anyway. Is there a way to make this work or is this simply not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recipient is important when you use `Messenger.Register` for `Messenger.Send` it is not important. However, there is a **known bug** in the <strike>`WeakReference`</strike> `WeakAction` implementation in MVVM that holds a reference to the recipient, although, it should release it.

In short, if you are inside a ViewModel, make sure that you call `Cleanup`. In a view, call `Messenger.Unregister(this)` in the `Unloaded` event e.g.

```
public MyView() {
    this.Unloaded += (o, e) => { Messenger.Unregister(this); }
}
```

In other classes your will have to either implement `IDisposable` or use some other mechanism to unregister the message recipient.

See also:

- [MVVM Light Listener not releasing / deterministic finalization for registered object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319862/mvvm-light-listener-not-releasing-deterministic-finalization-for-registered-obj/6324552#6324552)
- [Does mvvm light v3 unregister work properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919209/does-mvvm-light-v3-unregister-work-properly/6922299#6922299)
- [When to dispose ViewModel in MVVM Light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036873/when-to-dispose-viewmodel-in-mvvm-light/7037282#7037282)

Comment: There's a bug in WeakReference that holds a reference to the recipient? I thought the whole *point* of the class was to not hold a strong reference that would prevent an object from being garbage collected.

Comment: Yes, there is an Laurent is aware of it. The problem is related to the method you pass as a method handler. This method cannot be weak and, therefore, causes the object not being garbage collected. If the WeakReference would only track the object itself it would work. The solution to this is not trivial. See http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/discussions/235068.

Comment: Oh I thought you were saying there was a bug in the WeakReference class itself, which would have been surprising.

Comment: Modified the answer - it is Laurent's `WeakAction` implementation that causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I went into the source code and figured out what was happening. It's adding the recipient as a WeakReference to figure out if it's alive or not. I was just passing in `new object()` as the recipient and it wasn't firing because it thought my recipient was dead.